A simple question in quanum mechanics on position and momenum eigenstates
The eigenfunctions (eigenstates) for the momentum of a particle are given by the plane waves
$$\phi(x,t) = \sin(kx - \omega t)$$
If we sum a large number of these waves in a range from $0$ to $k_m$, we get something like this:
$$\psi(x, t) = \int_0^{k_m} \sin(kx -\omega t)dk = \frac{-\cos(k_m~x - \omega t) + \cos(\omega t)}{x} .$$
This represents a wave-packet concentrated at $x=0$. The bigger $k_m$ is, the narrower and higher the packet gets.
If we integrate over ALL $k$-values, from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$ we get an extremely narrow and infinitly high pattern when we plot it, and we refer to it by the delta-function $\delta(x)$. This detla-function is a position Eigenstate.
But why when we integrate $\delta(x)$ for all $x$ values, we don't get the momentum Eigenstates back? Insted we get
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\delta(x)dx = 1$$
and not a sine wave.
What should I do to get back the momentum eingenstate?

Why would you expect that? Roughly, i.e. non-rigorously speaking, what you've argued is that the FT of $1$ is the Dirac delta; if you apply the FT again (or its inverse), you get back $1$.

Your ‘t’ exhibits statistical fluctuations.

@TobiasFünke I expect that, because when I integrate over all k-space, I get the delta function (positon eigenstate). So why when I integrate over the entire x-space I don't get back the momentum eigenstate? Shouldn't the mathematical representation be symmetric? What to do to get the momentum eigenstates from the intgral then??

@my2cts Could you elaborate more please?

I have explained the reason.

@TobiasFünke I integrated a sine function, and I got a delta-function.

A plane wave has a well defined momentum, but occupies all positions equally. If you add up contributions from all positions, you get a delta function momentum eigenstate. If you take the Fourier Transform of the delta function, you get back a superposition of all position eigenstates. All positions have equal amplitude. There are some questions about how to normalize such a solution. See Normalizing the solution to free particle Schrödinger equation

Thank you. This is what an answer should look like.

First of all $\phi(x,t) = \sin(kx - \omega t)$ is not a momentum eigenstate. Its a super position of of $\exp(i(kx - \omega t))$ and $\exp(-i(kx - \omega t))$, which are momentum eigenstates for $+k$ and $-k$. However depending on how you define $\omega$ one of them does not fullfill the free particle Schrödinger equation, because their time development should be identical as they are both kinetic energy eigenstates with the same eigenvalue.
Now since for your question time development is irrelevant I suggest we look at the state $\exp(i(kx))$ instead.
Your equation now takes the form
$$\psi(x, t) = \int_{-k_m}^{k_m} \exp(ikx)dk = \frac{\exp(ikx) - \exp(-ikx)}{ix} = \frac{\sin(kx)}{x}$$
and in the limit of $k \rightarrow \infty$ you get $2 \pi \delta(x)$.
So it behaves similar similar to what you described.
What we found is that integrating over all momentum eigenstates, is the same as taking the Fourier transform of a constant in momentum space and yields a delta function in position space, which is a position eigenstate. Now I am not exactly sure what you expect happening when you integrate over the delta function, except that it should be normalized, if one would have used normalized momentum states, which I didn’t (hence the factor $2 \pi $). But to recover the wavefunction in momentum space you need to take the Fourier transform of the delta function, which yields a constant in momentum space and is exactly what you expect since you started out by integrating over all momentum eigenstates.

Ok. Nice. So, to get the momentum eingenstate back, I integrate using exp(-ikx). With a minus sign. I used a sine function for simplification, since I only consider the positve k-values.

I do not understand what you mean with "to get the momentum eingenstate back", you started by integrating over many momentum eigenstates. Why would you expect to get a single one "back" and how?

The funny part is, that the fourier transform of the $\delta$ also yields a constant, so the end result is the same as the one you got with your plain integration, though I do not understand the motivation behind that integration.

It's true. I get the momentum eigenstate back. exp(ikx) in the position space. What arn't you understand from my statement?

I am just a bit confused, beacause you appear to be talking about a differnet procedure now then described in your question, which you did not eloborate further. But if I could help make things more consistent in your head, I am happy with that.
